# Check if stream reference is NULL doesn't compile anymore

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, null, language-lawyer

I am compiling an outdated project with my latest gcc g++ compilers, (version > 6)

There is a class `CodeWriter` with an `ostream` reference variable.

```
class CodeWriter
{
  //private:
protected:
  ostream &m_stream;
public:
  CodeWriter(ostream &stream):m_stream(stream){}
  ~CodeWriter(){
    if(m_stream != NULL){
      m_stream.flush();
    }
  }
};
```

The class is quite large so I included only the relevant variables and functions.

As you can see the destructor seems to be comparing the reference to `NULL`.
This project compiled fine when I used it long back with old gnu toolchain.

But now it is throwing an error saying that there is no matching `operator !=` to compare `ostream` and `long int`.

Can anyone explain the rationale behind the change, and how I can fix this?

I would be happy to provide additional information/ include the whole class if required.

Comment: You misunderstand the code - it compares the stream object against NULL (which will invoke an overloaded operator of some sort or another). There is no such thing as a null reference (and so, it is not possible to check for one)

Comment: Re: "I included only the relevant variables and functions" Yes! Thank you! Exactly right!

Comment: Also note that for comparing _pointers_ to null you should be using `nullptr` now in C++11 or later instead of the macro `NULL`. (yes I know you do not have a pointer there but I am speaking to the intent of your null check).

Comment: @Snowman you are right, the same thing was showing up as an error in another part of this large legacy codebase, i am going mad trying to fix these things.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The code is not comparing the reference itself with `NULL`, but comparing the referenced-object with `NULL`. References can't be `NULL`, and it's impossible to compare the reference itself with `NULL`.

And

> This project compiled i when i used it long back with old gnu toolchain.

Because the behavior changed since C++11.

Before C++11, `std::ostream` could be implicitly converted to `void*` via [operator void*()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), which returns a null pointer if error has occurred on the stream. So the original intent of the code is to check whether the stream has no errors.

Since C++11 the conversion function was changed to `explicit operator bool()`, which returns `false` if error has occured. Note the function is declared as `explicit`, which means implicit conversion to `bool` is not allowed, so the code won't compile with C++11 again because `std::ostream` can't be converted to `bool` implicitly (and then to be compared with `NULL` (an integer literal)).

With a C++11-compatible compiler you can just change the code to

```
if (m_stream) {
  m_stream.flush();
}
```

Note that for [contextual conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions) even explicit conversion functions are considered. For the above code, `m_stream` will be converted to `bool` via `explicit operator bool()`, then the value would be used for the condition of `if`.

Answer (score 15):

Streams can always be evaluated in a boolean context, so just change it to:

```
if (m_stream) {
  m_stream.flush();
}
```

C++11 made the conversion to bool `explicit`. This is equivalent to `if (!m_stream.fail())`. Prior to C++11, this short-hand checkability was achieved by providing an (implicit!) conversion to `void*`, which is why your old code used to work.

The reason the code is checking for this, rather than just calling `m_stream.flush();` directly, is perhaps that the stream may have exceptions enabled for failure and that might throw, [update:] but, as @Arne pointed out, `flush` itself may fail and throw, too. If there are no exceptions, you can just skip the boolean check entirely.[/update]

Comment: `if (m_stream)` is equivalent to `if (!m_stream.fail())` (which allows `eof()`), not `if (m_stream.good())`, though this is irrelevant for "pure" output streams because they are not `eof()`. Also, if the intent is not to throw, then the solution is insufficient because the flush itself may cause `badbit` to be set and exceptions may be enabled for `badbit`.

Comment: I'll bet that the reason for testing whether the stream is valid before flushing it is the same as the reason for testing whether a pointer is null before deleting it: wanting to be "safe" without understanding the library specification.

Comment: @PeteBecker Are you referring to the answer you commented, or to the OP? In either case I'm not sure what you mean - if I understand correctly, OP has his own class, and checks if the resource was initialized to see if it needs flushing. Which part am I not getting?

Comment: @Sebi: There's no "checking if the resource was initialized" in the OP's code.

Comment: @Sebi - if a stream is in an invalid state, most operations on it become no-ops. Calling `flush` on a stream that has gone bad is harmless, and the test is pointless.

Answer (score 8):

The stream classes had an [`operator void*()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) in one of the base classes in pre-C++11. Of course the `void*` value could be compared to `NULL`.

In current C++ this is instead an `explicit operator bool()` which works in the context of the `if` statement, but not in a general expression.

The use of a `void*` was to avoid some unwanted conversions from `bool` that happened when we didn't have `explicit` operators.